# How to update the main view with drawer menu using KYDrawerController

Tags: ios, swift, menu

KYDrawerController
link - https://github.com/ykyouhei/KYDrawerController

Hello Guys,
It's lib and integrate slide menu, but here I am not able to update the main view from slide menu view(or drawer view) the view is always updated on Menu view only.

For example, I have four views as follows:-
1- main 
2- drawer (slide menu) 
2.1 - in the drawer, there is two button menu ie signup and login 
From the main menu I am able to access the drawer menu but when I used to click the menu button the view is updating on drawer menu only and the main view is as it is 
any suggestion..!
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to using [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/)

In the main view, add observer to some notification, and then in button's event handler to post that notification.